# Why does fixed point iteration only produce the solution greater than $1$ to the equation $Mx = e^x$ for $x \in \Bbb R$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation $Mx = e^x$, when $M > 0$. I know that the first solution must be at the tangent where the line $Mx$ crosses $e^x$, so $M$x has gradient $e^x$.
This leads to $x(e^x) = e^x$, $x = 1$

But all of the $M$ values greater than $e$ must yield exactly $2$ solutions. One that is larger than one and the other occurring between $0$ and $1$, (Rolle's theorem)

An approximation to a solution for any given $M$ is $\log(M)$, since $\log(M) + \log(x) = x$. This can be improved to give us $\log(M) + \log\log(M) = x$. The error to this approximation is $\log(1 - (\log(x))/(x))$, which rapidly approaches $0$ as $x$ gets larger. The error is this because $\log\log M = \log(x-\log(x)) = \log(x) + \log(1 - \frac{\log(x)}{x})$

Here's what I can't work out, $y = \log M$ has precisely one solution, whereas $y = x - \log(x)$ has two. Why does the approximation $\log M + \log\log M$ always gives the solution above $1$, and somehow ignores the other solution?

Comment: "so $M$ has gradient e^x$.  I don't see how a *constant* has a non-zero gradient.  Perhaps you meant to use a different word?

Comment: In the equation $\log M = x - \log x$, on the right hand side we can have $\log x$ small in relation to $x$ - that gets you the solution with $x > 1$ from the $x \approx \log M$ starting point - or we can have $x$ small in relation to $\log x$. The latter, starting from $\log x \approx - \log M$ resp. $x \approx \frac{1}{M}$ gets you to the solution with $x < 1$, provided that $M$ is large enough. For smaller $M$, neither $x$ nor $\log x$ can be easily ignored for a decent first approximation.

Comment: Do you know about cobweb plots? It can help you visualize the process.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer thank you so very much, that explains my issue with the assumption of log(x) being small very clearly. I reckon that solves the problem as log(x) is far larger than x for x<1. And yes M must be sufficiently large above e. Also just ignore my terribly laid out comments, I'm sort of new to this

Comment: Your title was vague so I changed it. It's possible you haven't heard of the term *fixed point iteration*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true that $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is small when $x$ is large, and therefore
the relative error of $\log M$ is small then.
But when $0 < x < 1$, $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is not necessarily small.
It can be quite large, in fact.

The error term $\log\left(1 - \frac{\log x}{x}\right)$ also can be
large when $0 < x < 1$.

In short, the assumptions you made in taking your approximations
are not true for $x < 1$, so you cannot expect those assumptions to find
an approximate solution for $x$ there.

Answer (score 3):

Transform your equation to

$$ln(M) + ln(x) = x$$

Then, look at the plot of $ln(x)$ and $x$:
[image]

As described in your question: If the curve $ln(x)$ is shifted upwards or downwards by $ln(M)$, it can intersect the main diagonal never (for $M \lt e$), once (for $M = e$) or two times (for $M \gt e$).

Comment: OP is evidently aware of the two solutions for $M>e$. The question was, "Why does the approximation $\log M + \log\log M$ always gives the solution above $1$, and somehow ignores the other solution?" Can you say anything about the approximation?

Answer (score 1):

You said in the post somewhere that $M > e$. Then $\log(M)>1$ and $\log(\log(M))>0$, thus $\log(M)+\log(\log(M)) > 1$. Therefore this approximation gives a solution above 1.

If $M < e$, then $\log(M)+\log(\log(M)) < 1$, but then the equation doesn't have a solution bigger than 1, as the derivative of $e^x-cx$ is $e^x-c$, which is positive when $x>1>\log(c)$ when $c<1$, and $e-c>0$ as well.

Comment: Even so, for $0<M<e$ there is no solution, since the tangent occurs at $M=e$.

Answer (score 1):

[Cobweb plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot), whether you've heard of them or seen them, are an excellent way to visualize the process of iteration.

In your case you're iterating $$f(x) = \log M + \log x $$ starting at $$x_0 = 1 $$ with the intent of solving $$x = f(x)$$

You should be able to see from the plot that the iteration converges.

Using linear stability analysis, you can find which of the two fixed points is stable. To do this you only need to computer $f'(x) = {1 \over x}$. It's a general theorem that when $|f'(x)| < 1$ the fixed point is stable and when $|f'(x)| > 1$ the fixed point is unstable, which means that in this case the only stable fixed point is the one for which $x > 1$.

[This](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucess29/page2/MATH3506Chapters//MATH3506Chapter5.pdf) is a good reference for the topic.

Answer (score 0):

set $\mu=\log M$ so that the equation becomes:
$$
 x = e^{x-\mu}
$$
suppose, for an example, that $M=e^2$ so $\mu=2$. take $x=0.3$ as a first guess, $x_0$. then
$$
x_1 = e^{ 0.3 - 2} = 0.1826... \\
x_2 = e^{0.1826 -2} = 0.1624...
$$
whilst the convergence is not particularly impressive, this iteration does home in on the root in $[0,1]$

in effect there are two 'directions' in which we can perform this iteration - the log route or the exp route - corresponding to a transformation and its inverse.  of the two fixed points, one is reached by each route.

Answer (score 0):

Can I just add something? With the method used to obtain the better approximation for the first root '$log(M) +log(log(M)) ≈ x$'. We can change $x ≈ \frac{1}{M}$ into '$x ≈ e^{1/M - log(M)}$'. Since, $logx = x - log(M)$ and $x$ is small. Though I'm not bothered to work out the error to that approximation

Comment: Is this an answer?